# Porting from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2 rspec have_selector test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, asset-pipeline, rspec2

I have a working Rspec controller test for my Rails 3.2 application which looks like this:

```
get 'home'
response.should have_selector("img", alt: "can-logo', src: "/assets/can-logo.png")
```

The test used to pass when we used Rails 3.2. Now with Rails 4.2, the test fails, and the error message looks like this:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("img", alt: "can-logo", src: "/assets/can-logo.png")

   expected following output to contain a <img alt='can-logo' src='/assets/can-logo.png'/>
```

The actual response has the following string:

```
<img src="/assets/can-logo-7c448d46877fafd50ab64f7abae0ca10719221722dd3d1ae257f24fc449efa1d.png" alt="can-logo 7c448d46877fafd50ab64f7abae0ca10719221722dd3d1ae257f24fc449efa1d">
```

(For reference, after much adjusting gems, tests, and some code, I can run the application locally and this use-case works fine, the Rails console works fine, and 685 out of 700 tests from our test suite pass. Of the 15 failing tests, about 5 look like this failure).

This looks like it's doing something funky with the assets, but I don't now how to get RSpec to ignore it, or how to serve the link without the funky "7c44..." string at the end of the image name or alt name.

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming have_selector can just take a CSS selector you should be able to do something like the following

```
response.should have_selector('img[alt^="can-logo-"][src^="/assets/can-logo-"][src$=".png"]')
```

Comment: It didn't work. I got a Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
       unexpected '/' after 'prefix_match'   error.

Comment: Is the argument of have_selector supposed to be a Ruby regex?

Comment: Sorry, I left out probably necessary quotes - updated answer.  Assuming the have_selector you're using is from Webrat, I don't think it took a regex since it converts it to XPath.  I could be wrong about that though, it's been a while since I used webrat

Comment: That didn't work either. I don't know how to tell if I'm using webrat.

Comment: What error did it give?  Look in your Gemfile to see if you're using webrat.

Comment: I have webrat 0.7.3 and capybara 2.6.0

Comment: hehehe -- ok - those are two tools designed to basically do the same thing, however Capybaras have_selector doesn't take :alt or :src options, so I would guess in that test you are actually using the webrat have_selector.  Depending on exactly what error you're getting now, maybe try updating nokogiri - Nokogiri::CSS.parse('img[alt^="can-logo-"][src^="/assets/can-logo-"][src$=".png"]') -  which is what webrat does, parses fine for me (it did fail with the error you had above without the quotes)

Comment: response.body.should =~ /img.*src="\/assets\/can-logo-.*png.*alt="can-logo.*>/
I decided to go old-school on this one for now, because I have other stuff to do besides learning xpath syntax.

Comment: ok -- what I posted was CSS syntax - not XPath -- (internally webrat converts it to XPath) as long as it's working for you